# Банальный парсинг таблицы методом через simple_html_dom

Tags: php, парсер, table, simple-html-dom

Добрый день, уважаемые форумчане. Помогите побороть такую проблему: есть переменная $page, которая содержит выведенную CURLом динамическую страницу. 
Вот ее кусок:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="result-list">
<div id='print_table'>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id='thetable'>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Город</th>
    <th>Улица</th>
    <th>Магазин</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="gradShop">
    <td>Минск</td>
    <td>ул.Ленина</td>
    <td>Продтовары</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gradShop">
    <td>Гомель</td>
    <td>ул.Паромная</td>
    <td>Магазин №5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь спарсить столбцы "Город", "улица" и "магазин", но выскакивает ошибка "Warning: file_get_contents(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\dashboard\test\rubrika\simple_html_dom.php on line 76"

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$table = array();
$html = file_get_html($page);

if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes))
{
foreach($html->find('table table-striped table-bordered') as $row)
{
$city= $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
$street = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;
$shop = $row->find('td',2)->plaintext;

$table[$city][$street][$shop] = true;
}
}
print_r($table).
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так. Вроде ж эллементарное дело).
Заранее прошу прощения за бардак с оформление кода

Comment: попробуйте без curl'а напрямую парсить, т.е., ссылку на сайт передавать аргументом в file_get_html();

Comment: Не получается, так как через curl я авторизуюсь (обычная basic аутентификация)

Comment: Может подскажите, откуда стоит хоть бы плясать? Переписать код или разобраться, что за ошибка такая?

Comment: в simple html dom метод file_get_html() аналогичен file_get_contents(), т.е. он используется для получения файла. А у вас файл уже получен курлом, поэтому надо использовать вместо file_get_html() другой метод, который принимает в виде аргумента именно html-разметку `str_get_html()` Посмотрите тут: [How to modify HTML elements?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)